# WebApplicationInitializer not working in ubuntu 8.5.23

Tags: java, spring, tomcat8.5

I was trying to deploy a Spring MVC project with no web xml configuration *(The configurations are written in Class level through WebApplicationInitializer)* in Tomcat 8.5.23 running in Ubuntu and MacOS. It is successfully deployed in both the cases. In Mac, it gives me the output but in Ubuntu, it is giving the 404 error. The same exact war is deployed in both and the same tomcat distribution. Since both the wars are same I am clueless on what went wrong.

Edit: I am not able to see any logs also written regarding this in Tomcat logs

Comment: Is there a log? What exactly do you mean by not working? white screen, error on startup, nothing happening, the server starts up and serves empty responses..... so many possibilities

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the logs

Comment: It is showing 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the Java version. WebApplicationInitializer will work only with Java 1.8. but in Ubuntu Java version was 1.7, so it didn't work.